# Datetime conversion to time

Tags: python, datetime

I have converted `offset_str` to time for `offset_str = '01:00:00'` as following:

```
offset_time = datetime.strptime(offset_str, '%H:%M:%S').time()

offset_delta = timedelta(hours=offset_time.hour)
```

How can I convert `offset_str = "-1 day, 18:00:00"` to time?
I have already tried by following commands, but it did not work.

```
offset_str_list = offset_str.split(',') 

offset_time_h = dt.datetime.strptime(offset_str_list[1].replace(" ", ""), '%H:%M:%S').time()

delta = dt.timedelta(hours = -23)

offset_time = ((dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(1,1,1),offset_time_h) + delta).time())
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be a negative offset (i.e., before the date)? If so, why not just convert to the positive offset then subtract the times?

Comment: unrelated: where do you get `offset_str`? It looks like `str(timedelta_obj)`. Could you avoid calling `str()` on `timedelta_obj` and use it directly  instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after but for what it's worth:

```
import datetime
offset_str = "-1 day, 18:00:00"
# break up string
off_amt,off_time = offset_str.split(',')
off_time = off_time.strip()
time_val,time_increment = off_amt.split(' ')
# Get today's date YYYY-MM-DD
now = datetime.datetime.today()
now_ymd = datetime.datetime.strftime(now,'%Y-%m-%d')
#Create date and time string, convert to a datetime object
now_ymd = now_ymd + ' ' + off_time
use_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(now_ymd, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#Calculate new date
new_date = use_date+datetime.timedelta(days=int(time_val))
print "old date ", use_date
print "new date ", new_date
```

Output:

```
old date  2016-01-15 18:00:00
new date  2016-01-14 18:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/#quickstart). It's the first example of the quickstart. 
For example to have the date of the previous hour from now:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> utc = arrow.utcnow()
>>> utc.replace(hours=-1)
<Arrow [2016-01-15T14:36:12.820122+00:00]>
>>> str(utc.replace(hours=-1))
'2016-01-15T14:36:12.820122+00:00'
>>> str(utc.replace(days=-1))
'2016-01-14T14:36:12.820122+00:00'
>>> utc.replace(hours=-1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2016-01-15 14:36:12'
```